# On the first column. I have codes like 2abc and 22abc ı want 2's to become 02abc

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of barcodes. Like 2abc, 3sdh, 23dgs, 41eds extc. I will match these to a list by using VLOOKUP with *first two numbers* of the barcodes. But first ı need to make 2abc to 02abc, 3dsh to 03 sdh extc.

**I need to put infront of the number if it is just one digit number.**

I have figured ı can use VLOOKUP after ı have first two characters as numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISERR(INT(LEFT(A1,2))),TEXT(LEFT(A1,1),"0#")&MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)), A1)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I changed a little bit and used this  =IF(ISERR(INT(LEFT(A6;2)));TEXT(LEFT(A6;1);"0#");(LEFT(A6;2))) I have translated this code so there might be some issues.